# VB Convert RGB String to Hex

Tags: vb.net

The title pretty much explains my issue. I need to convert a single string RGB value into a Hex value. I can do this if the value is given in three separate strings, but as the RGB is given from a color picker I'm unable to do this - unless I split the string which I don't want to do as I feel it's unnecessary.

I want to be able to convert a string such as: `0, 112, 192` into it's hexadecimal equivalent. Can I convert the entire string or do I have to split the string into its RGB parts first?

Comment: Why would you feel splitting the string is unnecessary?  It's not like you're converting a 3-byte integer into its hex representation.  You're converting three separate 1-byte integers into their hex representation.  That's three separate strings.  This is a trivial question anyway... one that you know the answer to.

Comment: Are you using the ColorDialog?  I'm not sure how that is returning the string you show?  Can you not just access the `Color` property of the dialog and then access the individual R, G and B components and convert them to hex?

Comment: Have you tried something like this:  `colorDialog1.Color.ToArgb().ToString("X8")`

Answer (score 0):

Since you can have varying numbers of decimal digits for the RGB value, you'll need to separate it before you convert it.

```
s1 = "0, 112, 192"
s2 = ""
For Each s As String In s1.Split(",")
  s2 &= CInt(s).ToString("x2")
  Next s
```